# is there any tool or software that will give the list of dlls and registry data that an application is using?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

Is there any tool that give the list of dlls, registry loc and other files/data that an application need when it gets launched?

I basically need this info to know what are all such files/data that IE6 uses when it get launched in windows XP? So that, I would try to get the answer why versions of IE are tightly coupled with windows OS and also we are trying an experiment how to run IE6 on vista or win7? Not thru existing [XP mode of windows 7](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2009/06/24/using-windows-7s-xp-mode-to-run-ie-6-and-ie-7-side-by-side/). But like an virtualized application?

Thanks for any inputs.

Answer (score 1):

procmon http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For DLL [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Answer (score 0):

At the command line: `tasklist /M`

IE6 is part of the OS, and as such has dependencies, either directly or indirectly, on basically everything in %windir%/system32.  You might be able to find a subset that "works good enough" but you'll always have something that is a little wonky because of some mis-matched DLLs.